# Change target about two or more apps in Visual Studio (Windows phone 8.1 store app)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I need to make two or more apps that use the same code, but with slightly different colors and UI. Unfortunatelly I am not using MVC/MVVM. In Android and iOS development there is some "target" thing in the IDE, that makes the second app another one (in the store) but the classes and screens are shared between the first and the second. For example:
for the first app I need a button to be green;
for the second app I need this button to be invisible;

Is there a way to set target build, and to know which app I am targeting in Visual Studio?

Comment: You can try to use a Shared project, containing the common code and XAML, and then make two target apps that use that same shared project and introduce the specific styles

Comment: Where is this whole process described? Sounds like it is exactly what I am looking for? How is this called? A reference would be helpful.

Comment: For a fully functional shared project usage, you need Visual Studio 2015. Shared projects were introduced in VS2013 for making Universal Windows Applications, but the management may be a bit limited. In VS 2015 you can add a new generic Shared project to a solution and then reference it from any other project.